# Using wmic to get workgroup in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic, workgroup

I'm not really versed in batch file, but I am trying to get the workgroup using `wmic`. I've been trying different things with the `for` options. So far this is the best result I have gotten.

```
for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic computersystem get workgroup') do echo %%a
```

This returns what I want, but it is also echoing something else because it gives an `echo is off` message. I also want to set the workgroup to a variable such as something like this.

```
for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic computersystem get workgroup') do set "myVar=%%a"
```

This doesn't return anything though. I'm assuming I need to use `tokens` and/or `delims`, but I just don't have the knowledge to get it to work correctly.

If anyone could assist me on this I would be much appreciated and perhaps it will help me learn a bit more about how to use the `for` loop. I know this is probably something very simple, so please excuse me for being so ignorant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It is also echoing something else because it gives an `echo is off`

This is because `wmic` is (badly written and) outputs a blank line at the end of the output.

You can use `findstr /r /v "^$"` to remove the blank line.

Using a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in (`wmic computersystem get workgroup ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do set myVar=%%i
echo %myVar%
endendlocal
```

Using a command line:

```
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %i in (`wmic computersystem get workgroup ^| findstr /r /v "^$" ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do @set myVar=%i && echo %myVar%
```

Notes:

- `for /f` loops through the `wmic` output.
- `skip=1` skips the header line (containing `VariableValue`)
- `findstr /r /v "^$"` removes the trailing blank line from the `wmic` output.

Example output:

```
> wmic computersystem get workgroup
Workgroup
WORKGROUP


> for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %i in (`wmic computersystem get workgroup ^| findstr /r /v "^$" ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do @set myVar=%i && echo %myVar%
WORKGROUP

>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: This works for what I need. Thank you for the help and the references to help me understand what I am doing.